# Индикатор работы процесса

Tags: архитектура, java, javafx, шаблоны-проектирования

Как правильно организовать индикацию состояния выполнения задачи, с *минимальным* взаимодействием с интерфейсом пользователя? Например, программа выполняет долгий расчёт(возможно в отдельном потоке), а пользователю отображается прогресс бар в `GUI`. Думал создать какой-нибудь промежуточный объект, который будет передаваться задаче.А этот, назовём его `ProgressMonitor` будет посылать сообщение интерфейсу о том, что процесс идёт. В общем, выполняемая задача не должна знать о `GUI`. Желательно, чтобы и `GUI` знал поменьше о задаче, в идеале нужно лишь выполнить функцию `StartTask`, а всю работу будет выполнять задача.

Может кто-нибудь знает другое решение? Есть ли паттерн проектирования на этот случай?
На всякий случай дополню, что пишу на `Java`. В качестве библиотеки для `GUI` использую `JavaFX`.

Comment: похоже на паттерн MVC + Observer для уведомления ГУИ о состоянии процесса

Comment: Ну, по сути этим ProgressMonitor я и реализую что-то вроде Observer.

Comment: ну а если тебе индикацию надо... бери весь процесс как 100% дели на  сколько надо и уведомляй по достижению прогресса

Comment: С определением готовность процесса я уж справлюсь :) Тут весь вопрос именно в архитектуре взаимодействия процесса и GUI.Думал, мало ли, есть возможность как-то по другому делать.

Comment: а как тут сделаешь по другому? если есть измеримая величина то можно считать по ней (напр. ждать 15 секунд, скопировать 1 гб, скопировать 500 файлов). тогда нужно делать гуи листенером а "выполнялка" будет посылать ивенты о обновлении статуса (1 секунда прошла, 1 файл скопировался, 1мб скопировался). 

если у вас задача с недерменированным временем выполнения, тогда лучше просто диалог типа: "подожди пользователь и посмотри на наш красивый модальный диалог с вращающейся пимпочкой/гипножабой"

Comment: Я же написал, как определить степень готовности я знаю, читайте коммент выше.

Answer (score 2):

Если с минимальным взаимодействием, тогда нужно чтобы по умолчанию интерфейс считал что все идет правильно, и показывал индикатор работы, а в логике встроить условие или таймер которое бы фиксировало сбой в работе и только в случае сбоя сообщало интерфейсу о неполадках, таким образом интерфейс будет взаимодействовать с логикой только в случае сбоя, если нужно могу вечером пример накидать.